# How do I determine the earthing arrangement for my outbuilding?

Tags: electrical

I have an outbuilding, which I believe is earthed by a TT system (because it's not bonded to the supply earth and has an RCD), but I can't find any earth inspection point.

Is there an easy way for me to confirm that it is, and the the earthing is adequate?

Comment: Pictures of the panel in your out building (with the panel cover _carefully_ removed) will help the electricians here determine if there is earthing wiring run, and they can then point you in the direction of what to chase down.

Comment: Ah right - there should be a separate "just earth" wire leaving from the panel? How bad is it if there isn't one?

Comment: Can you trace the earthing connection from the outbuilding consumer unit's earth bar to the earth spike?  Are there bonding wires back to the consumer unit from receptacle earth connections?